# How can I improve performance of a many-to-many SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, join, schema

I have a many-to-many relationship between Books and Genres. For example "The Hobbit" Book may have the Genres "Kids", "Fiction" and "Fantasy".

Here's the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE "genre" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
;
CREATE TABLE "book_genres" (
    "book_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "book" ("id"),
    "genre_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "genre" ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT book_genres_pkey PRIMARY KEY (book_id, genre_id)
)
;
CREATE TABLE "book" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "price" real NOT NULL
)
;
```

And the indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX "book_genres_36c249d7" ON "book_genres" ("book_id");
CREATE INDEX "book_genres_33e6008b" ON "book_genres" ("genre_id");
CREATE INDEX "book_5a5255da" ON "book" ("price");
```

Row counts:

- genre: 30
- book_genres: 800,000
- book: 200,000

I am trying to write a query in SQL which brings back all the Books for specific Genres ordered by price without duplicates.

Here's my query which does this:

```
SELECT name, price 
FROM book 
WHERE book.id 
IN 
    (SELECT book_id 
    FROM book_genres
    WHERE genre_id = 1
    OR genre_id = 2)
ORDER BY price LIMIT 10
```

My problem is performance. This query can take up to 2000ms to execute. How can I improve the performance?

I have full control over the database (Postgres 9.3) so can add views, indexes or denormalise. I am also using Django so could perform multiple queries perform operations in memory using Python/Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT b.name, b.price
FROM book b
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM book_genres bg
    WHERE bg.book_id = b.id 
    AND bg.genre_id IN( 1 , 2)
    )
ORDER BY b.price 
LIMIT 10
        ;
```

The order by price+LIMIT can be a performance killer: check the query plan.

PLUS: replace the one-column indices by a "reversed" index:
make book_id a FK into books.id
and (maybe) omit the surrogate key id

---

```
CREATE TABLE book_genres
        ( book_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES book (id)
        , genre_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES genre (id)
        , PRIMARY KEY (book_id, genre_id)
        ) ;
CREATE INDEX ON book_genres  (genre_id,book_id);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made the changes you suggested. Performance is the same as my current query. One thing to note is that the performance gets progressively worse using `OFFSET` (e.g. `OFFSET 500`). Would the planner output help?

Comment: (you did vacuum analyze after the table modification?) Remove the `order by price LIMIT xxx` and the performance will probably get better (if there are not too many rows satisfying your condition) OFFSET can make things even worse.

Comment: "you did vacuum analyse?" - That was the problem!! I hadn't run that. Now I have and my original query runs sub 20ms every time when not using `OFFSET` and up to 200ms when using it (which is tolerable). Awesome work, thanks for pointing me to the solution.

Comment: You should make that a habit: after modifying a table content(distribution), or altering its structure (adding indexes, etc) run `VACUUM ANALYZE the_table;` on it to refresh the statistics.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases you can improve you performance using `JOIN` instead of subqueries (Although it depends on many factors so ) :

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
   SELECT b.name, b.price 
   FROM book b JOIN book_genres g ON b.book.id = g.book_id 
                              AND g.genre_id = 1
   UNION

   SELECT b.name, b.price 
   FROM book b JOIN book_genres g ON b.book.id = g.book_id 
                              AND g.genre_id = 2
)
ORDER BY price LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my first try as well. Unfortunately it brings back duplicates if the Book is both in Genre 1 and Genre 2. Also, adding `DISTINCT` massively degrades performance.

Comment: @donturner : I've just started).Try another one ^ . Concerning the first one : have you tried to `group by`?

Comment: I tried `GROUP BY`, performance was the same as `DISTINCT`. Unfortunately your new query takes around 3000ms to execute. Would the query planner output help?